# ASP.NET MVC4 Searching for controller in wrong area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using default MVC routing setup:

> ```
>         routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
>
>         routes.MapRoute(
>             name: "Default",
>             url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
>             defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
>         );
> ```

I have area defined as:

```
public class AdministrationAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Administration";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Administration_default",
                "Administration/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

And I have a controller in that area:

```
namespace XXX.Areas.Administration.Controllers
{
    public class CountryController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
///
        }
    }
}
```

When I type

> /Administration/Country

it works good as it is desired.

When I type

> /Country

action still gets invoked, though view is not found so I get an error.

Why is MVC accepting

> /Country

as valid route? I don't have another CountryController in non-area zone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add NameSpace in the Global.asax file for the default Route.

```
var route = routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }, // Parameter defaults,
    new[] { "YourNameSpace.Controllers" }
);
```

Add NameSpace in the `AreaRegistration` class present in your `Area`

```
public class MyArea : AreaRegistration
{
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "test",
            "Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "MyProjectNameSpace.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

I have a following area in my application. So the below highlighted section is out concerned Controller. ok.

**Figure -1**

[image]

I typed Url : `http://localhost:2474/ActionFilterAttribute/index`

Before moving toward the destination. I will show you some how I initialized my test. I added a Reference of **[RoureDebugger. You can get the Dll from this location](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/13/routedebugger-2.aspx)**. Then I added a line of code in my Global.asax file under `Application_Start` Handler.

```
RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);
```

So, finally using the above mentioned Url, I started debugging the application. Finally I saw the below picture.

**Figure -2**

[image]

**Question**

> action still gets invoked, though view is not found so I get an error.

**Answer**

So if you pay attention to the above highlighted `Route`, well, this is the `Default Route`. This pattern is matched with Url as mentioned above. But View will not be found in this case and that's the reason your `Controller Action Method` is Invoked.

---

**Before moving to the next part that why did I get 404. I will show you some test I did in my sample application.**

I created a class which derives from `ActionFilterAttribute` like below. This contains only one `Override` that's called `OnResultExecuting`. This Handler executes before executing the `View` corresponding to particular `Action`

The purpose of Creating this class is just to verify what is happening with `RouteData` and `DataTokens`.

```
public class MyActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;

        if (viewResult != null)
        {
            var razorEngine = viewResult
                                        .ViewEngineCollection
                                        .OfType<RazorViewEngine>()
                                        .Single();

            var viewName = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(viewResult.ViewName) ? 
                                                  viewResult.ViewName :         
                  filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

           var razorview = razorengine
                           .FindView
                           (
                               filtercontext.Controller.ControllerContext, 
                               viewname, 
                               viewResult.MasterName, 
                               false
                           ).View as RazorView;
        }

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

### **Ok. Let's come back to the original question. Why did I get 404?**

Your `Controller` will be picked up by the default base route `{controller}/{action}` before it checks the `Area Route` and therefore will look for the `View` in the `Root/Views` instead of in the `Area/views`.

To examine this, I set the debugger in the Action Method of Controller inside the Area and found that that there is no `DataToken` Information when the Requested url is without `Area Name`. let's see more details about `DataToken` in `Debug` Mode

**Figure -3**

[image]

If you pay attention to the `ControllerContext`, I enumerated the `DataTokens`, which is showing no key/Value. It's because no view is found pertaining to that controller under the `Root Directory`

How can you say that the currently located Directory is Root Directory? Proof is below

**Figure -4**

[image]

There is no Namespace or any Area mentioned in the `RouteData` values. right?

Now let's move to the `RouteData` that matched the pattern which is containing the `Area Name`. So, this time my Url is : `http://localhost:2474/mypractise/ActionFilterAttribute/index` and below is the `RouteData` matched by **[URLRoutingModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643022/asp-net-mvc-what-is-urlroutingmodule)**

**Figure -5**

[image]

Please pay attention to the highlighted section, this time the Route matched belongs to `AreaName` pattern and matched value is false for the Default Route which belongs to some `RouteData` at Root Directory. Right?

My final details for the `DataTokens` in case of above mentioned requested Url. You can see the Namespace details and Area details this time.

**Figure -6**

[image]

**Conclusion** :

When the `Controller` is inside the Area and your `DataTokens` are not showing the information for `Area` , `NameSpace` and `UseNameSpaceFallback` informations. That means you will get 404. As mentioned in Figure-4, your requested Url was correct, so you got the `DataTokens` and As mentioned in Figure 3, DataTokens were not shown because the requested Url does not contains the `Area Name` and despite of the fact that you have got the `RouteData` as mentioned in Figure 2 because it's a default Url Pattern. Finally try to execute the third line of code in `OnResultExecuting`. It will show null because View is not found.

Hope this explanation will help you.

Comment: Very thorough! The only thing missing is the simple explanation as to *why* :) great job non the less. Up vote from me

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed explanation on this question. I'm running into a similar problem and really appreciated an easy to read answer.

Answer (score 7):

Check it. Modify the default route in your *Global.ascx.cs* file like so.

```
var route = routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new string[] { "APPLICATION_NAMESPACE.Controllers.*" }
);

route.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
```

EDIT:

My apologies. It seemed like you *didn't* want it to do this as well as know *why*.

You are running into the fact that the default routing will look for anything that is a controller. Even if it's in an Area. You can overcome this default behavior by simply adding the `namespaces` parameter to the route and specify what the default routing should be looking for with controllers.

The solution that I provided above is merely a fix if you wanted to not serve the view of an area *outside* the area itself.

There is a great article on why this is occurring [here](http://malvinly.com/2011/06/16/asp-net-mvc-areas/).

Comment: Sorry but the query is how the controller in Area got executed without typing the `Area Name` before `Controller` Name

Comment: Your solution fixed my problem, and since you're named member, I'll grant you 25 points for the effort. User2015869 - Your explanation beats any MVC book.

Comment: The `UseNamespaceFallback` nailed it for me... specifying just the namespaces aren't enough...