# How to prevent request an action without specifying its area in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have some controllers in root and I've registered its rout like this as default:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And I have an area named 'Admin' which its rout registered like this:

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Admin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Default_Admin",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

My problem is that user can request an action inside a controller (e.g: UserController/Index) in Admin area without specifying its area in url.

I mean these urls both are same:

```
http://localhost:2374/Admin/Default1/Index
http://localhost:2374/Default1/Index
```

And I want to avoid the second url.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your Default1 controller is under the right namespace? You need to make sure the controller is in the Area's specific namespace in order to restrict outside routing

Comment: @WeTTTT yes I'm sure, you can test it, you'll see the reaction. thanks

Comment: See if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224428/asp-net-mvc4-searching-for-controller-in-wrong-area